# How can we set Subscriber Status correctly using MC Connector

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

There is a common issue with Marketing Cloud when connected with Salesforce that it assumes new Subscribers are Status = "Active". Typically we get around this by running an automation to correctly insert the Subscriber record, however we have a Journey that triggers off Salesforce Data (Person) Account INSERT.

As soon as the Subscriber is inserted into this Journey they are added to the All Subscribers list (that or as soon as the first email activity is reached, which in our case is immediately) in which case the automation will not run in time to insert the record before Marketing Cloud does. What are ways we can correctly setup the Status in this case?

Comment: If you import subscribers into All Subscribers instead of letting MC add them when an email is sent, you screw up the whole synch between the clouds. Why would you want to add subscribers who are not in the "Active" status to the All Subs list?

Comment: If their status is suppose to be unsubscribed. Have a check of this in the journey and send them down another path where there is no Email Activity (assuming they still need to be in the journey). Or just don't add them to the journey.

Comment: @CodeRage How does it screw it up? I've done this plenty times before and as long as the PersonContactID is used its fine. People opt out of marketing emails, but still need to receive transactional sends. As mentioned in my post MC will still insert them into the All Subscribers but as Active. We need this to be unsubscribed so not marketing campaigns get sent to them.

Comment: @user3274635 These are transactional emails, so we *have* to send them an email.

Comment: @DeploymentFailure I see. I am afraid I can't think of any easy solution for this. The we have solved similar cases is to have a flag on the Person Account that indicates whether we can market to this person or not. And then not sending any emails to the contact or entering it to any journeys.

I guess you could also add the Subscriber to the All Subscribers list with an outbound API call from Salesforce when the Person Account is created.

Comment: @user3274635 I did also think about this option (although I would like to avoid custom development in CRM) but this still may not guarantee the record is not already created as the callout in CRM will be asynchronous and not necessarily immediate.